# NMOS High frequency, fast bi-directional switching, 12V 100A

Tags: mosfet

**Context**

I want to charge a battery bank from a car alternator. Either side may have a higher voltage than the other, e.g.:

- Battery bank can be 14V while alternator-side is 12V (engine off, solar charging)
- Battery bank can be 12V while alternator-side is 14V. (engine on, solar not charging)

I thought of using a relay, but the battery may be able to draw a higher current than the alternator can support. Therefore, switching to control the current is essential.

The current is very high, e.g. 100A, and therefore fast switching is needed to reduce heat build-up. By using MOSFETs in parallel, the current and consequent heat is reduced significantly.

To reduce jolting action on the alternator when switching on, and therefore reduce stress and increase lifetime, I imagine the switching ought to be high-frequency. Maybe 1000Hz is sufficient?

I'm interested in using NPN, because they're much cheaper. I'll use a cheap DC-DC boost circuit to provide 25V for driving the gate.

**Schematic**

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fq945x.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

**Problem**

1) Should the body diodes face towards eachother or away from eachother?

2) In the diagram, the connection is:
*Battery -> Vd -> Vs + Vs <- Vd <- Alternator*

Will Vs be floating when both MOSFETs are off? E.g. is it possible that Vs becomes 0V and therefore violates the Vgs max rating?

I was thinking that by facing the body diodes towards eachother, Vs will never be less than the highest voltage minus the drop over the body diode.

Also, I'm wondering if current has to be able to flow from Vs? Again, in the current schematic, with body diodes against eachother, I don't see how Vs would allow any current to flow.

3) I'm in particular worried about violating the Vgs< +-20V rating.

- When Signal=5V then Vg=25V, max Vs=14V, max Vgs +14V.
- When Signal=0V then Vg=0, Vs=(0-14V?), max Vgs -14V.

Is this correct?

Comment: How will this charge your battery when alternator voltage is less than battery voltage. Maybe you need to explain functionality a bit more. What it looks like you are designing is a MOSFET solid-state-relay - go look it up because it might help you realize that a floating source connection may prove problematic.

Comment: Sometimes the engine/alternator is not running. The car battery will then be at ~12.3V and may drain the battery bank. That's why it needs to be bi-directional. When the engine/alternator is running, the voltage will be at ~14.0V. I wrote this in the beginning of the question.

Comment: As mentioned, a solid-state-relay would not allow me to control current.

Comment: Floating source problem could be alleviated simply by reversing the MOSFETs?  Battery-Vs-Vd-Vd-Vs-Alternator  ?

Comment: "The car battery will then be at ~12.3V and may drain the battery bank. That's why it needs to be bi-directional. "  So you never want to charge the car battery from the battery bank?  That seems like a good reason the switch can be uni-directional so it will block the reverse current from flowing.

Comment: In some cases it may be desirable to charge the car battery, particularly when parked up in freezing weather, to maintain SoC. But if you think an uni-directional solution would be a lot easier, I'll be glad to hear it. I can't see how though, without using a diode.

Comment: I've added a 100k resistor to prevent Vs floating

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1)  You can face the body diodes either way and it will work, but I usually have the source terminal of both MOSFETs connected together.  That way your gate-source driver is only between two points rather than 3.  For NMOS this would mean the diodes point away from each-other.

2)  To turn on the MOSFET you only need to develop a voltage between the gate and source.  You don't need any sustained current to flow through the source.  Some small amount of current will flow between gate and source when the gate is initially driven as the gate capacitance charges.

2/3)  If you use a proper gate driver with the sources tied together you won't have to worry about the gates floating because the driver will always determine the gate source voltage.  One way to drive NMOS FETs is with an isolated supply that was made for gate driving, combined with a gate driver chip.

For example you could use this floating power supply...

MGJ6D121505LMC-R7

Vin = 9V to 18V.  Dual isolated output voltages +15V and -5V with shared floating ground.  Available on Digikey for $16.75.

http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/murata-power-solutions-inc/MGJ6D121505LMC-R7/811-3235-1-ND/6202209

With this gate driver chip

1EDI60N12AFXUMA1

Available for $2.87 on Digikey.

http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/infineon-technologies/1EDI60N12AFXUMA1/1EDI60N12AFXUMA1CT-ND/5962298

When using MOSFETs in parallel you have to worry about the fact that they don't all switch on at exactly the same time.  So one of them always takes a lot of current for a short period just following a switch, which stresses it and leads to early failure.  Also they will share current, but it won't be 100% equal so some will get hotter than others.  You might have an easier time just using one MOSFET that is rated for 100A.  For example you could use this one...

IXTN660N04T4

It is available for $19.60 on Digikey.

http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/ixys/IXTN660N04T4/IXTN660N04T4-ND/6053919

It is rated at 660A continuous current provided that you can cool it. It has a 0.85 milli-ohm on resistance. So at 100A the drop across it would be 85mV and 8.5W of heat would be generated.

The device has a large isolated pad on the back side that has a junction to pad thermal resistance rated at 0.144 C/W. The pad has screw holes for mounting. So you could theoretically put that isolated pad right on the frame of the vehicle to sink out as much heat as you need.

IXYS corporation sells other similar MOSFETs if you need a different package style.

I see you have a 1 ohm resistor as over voltage protection for your alternator.  If your alternator can really put out 100A then you probably need a much bigger resistor.

Comment: The main advantage of paralleling, is that the current gets divided, e.g. P = (I/number of MOSFETs)^2 x Ron.
For 2 MOSFET, power is 50w. For 6 MOSFETs, power is 5.5w. The MOSFET you recommended has a very high Ron, so there is no benefit of a single large current.

Comment: I agree about peak current capability. The AP99T03GP can handle 200A continuous. So the problem is mainly if current is unequal and results in a lot of heat. But I'm hoping that the high heat will increase resistance, leading to a natural equilibrium of equally distributed current.

Comment: I read just now about 1EDI60N12AFXUMA1, but it seems the main advantage of using a driver chip is that it provides galvanic isolation. Are there any other advantages over the schematic I posted in the question?

Comment: How much should the OVP resistor be? I'm worried that too high resistance will cause some of the over-voltage to leak into the main circuit.

Comment: Could you say something about why it's not a problem that Vs is in the middle, and why it won't be floating (and potentially violating the Vgs_max spec)... I'm a bit worried about spending an hour soldering everything and then frying the MOSFETs from some small mistake like not having a 100k resistor between Vd and Vs.

Comment: @user95482301 If 6 of the AP99T03GP FETs are paralleled then the effective on resistance is 2.5mOhm / 6 = 0.42mOhm.  0.42mOhms would lead to 4.2W at 100A.  I agree that there would be less heat using the parallel FETs but I disagree that 0.85mOhms would be considered a high on-resistance.  8.5W of heat is not a problem for the miniBLOC, SOT-227 package.

Comment: @user95482301 You are correct that increases in resistance with temperature result in natural current balancing.  But it will still be somewhat unequal.

Comment: @user95482301 In addition to isolation the 1EDI60N12AFXUMA1 also has high gate drive current which is necessary if you want to switch FETs with low losses.  The circuit you posted can provide a maximum of 250mA of gate drive (because of the 100 ohm resistors).  Also your 5V control signal will never be able to turn off the to PNP BJT.  You need some sort of level translation between the control signal and the base of the BJTs.  The 1EDI60N12AFXUMA1 provides the driver stage and level translation in one package.

Comment: @user95482301 With respect to the OVP resistor, the problem was not the value but rather the wattage.  A 1 ohm 1W resistor can only take 1A, which is way less than your alternator can output.  Really you don't need a resistor at all, just a Zener diode (or several of them in parallel) that are capable of absorbing any transients on the power bus.  If you are just worried about surges and spikes then the diode(s) should be picked based on its pulsed energy rating.  If you are concerned about sustained over-voltage then you will need to pick some with large heat-sink tabs.

Comment: @user95482301 In your design D1 and D3 prevent excessive voltage on the gate.  When using an isolated driver such as the 1EDI60N12AFXUMA1 the gate voltage will not go more than +15 or -5V with respect to the FET source because the driver chip is always putting a defined voltage on the gate.

Comment: Sorry, you're right. I accidentally looked at 'IXTN60N50L2' (100mOhm) instead of 'IXTN660N04T4' (0.85mOhm). Apparently my primary distributor doesn't have that component.